# Deploy Pfsense to make a cheap AirPort Extreme

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-flash-drive, print-server

i was wondering if Pfsense could be deployed on a cheap old system to make a poor mans Airport Extreme (apple's router+ usb drive share + printer share) ?? AirPort Extreme besides being a router can turn any external USB hard drive into a secure drive you can share across your Wi-Fi network. plus it can even connect a printer and share it wirelessly .(see attachment)

I dont want to use pfsense as a firewall at all. basically as secure or unsecure as Apple Express .

thanks

amit

Comment: So all you want is drive and printer sharing ?

Comment: DRIVE PRINT SHARING PLUS WIFI ROUTER (ALL IN ONE)

Comment: @lawrence yes plus wifi-router . my query then is deploy pfSense (or some other os) to create a **wifi router + drive share + print sharing** from cheap hardware .

Comment: You'll most likely pay more in electricity to use an old PC as a "Wi-Fi AP" / "home gateway router" / NAS than the cost of buying a cheap (perhaps used) Wi-Fi router.